# SSL certificate in different port

Tags: asp.net, ssl, certificate, port, openfire

Hi! My problem:
I use web-application in 443 port, with SSL certificate, and this application have web-service in javascript.
Web service connect different port 7443 and also use same certificate.
But certificate to 7443 port no add, so web service no work.
To add a certificate to 7443 port, should go to address https://mysite.com:7443, and add certificate - service work.

I need that when you add a certificate in 443 port, it is added automatically to 7443 port in same domain.
It's possible?
What to do?
Thank!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved this problem, for correctly work need TRUSTED CERTIFICATE.
1.This certificate i took FREE in http://www.startssl.com/
2.Took steps to obtain i convert certificate the correct format for IIS Manager, import to IIS.
3.Openfire. Descripted my key:
"Import Private Key and Signed Certificate Created by CA
Some CAs will do the certificate creation and signing work for you.
In this case all you need to do is import the private key and signed certificate into Openfire.
Openfire will accept encrypted private keys (AES algorithms are currently not supported)
and also not encrypted keys. If you need to decrypt a private key you can use OpenSSL.
Just execute openssl rsa -in ssl.key -out decryptedssl.key where ssl.key is the encrypted file and decryptedssl.key is the
new file to generate with the decrypted key.
4.Import certificate in admin panel, and check settings in openfire.(SSL, port number)
5.Restart openfire.
Correctly work!
Thank you all!

Sorry my bad, bad english..